# i cant fix the .map on http post client

Tags: json, angular, http, get

```
public postForObjecty(endpoint: any, data: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let url = this.createBasicUrl(endpoint);
            let _data = this.arrangeData(data);
            let headers: any = new Headers()
            let token = `Bearer ${RestProvider.BEARER_TOKEN}`;
            headers.append('Authorization', token);
            this.http.post(url, _data, { headers: headers })
                .map((res: { json: () => any; }) => res.json())
                .subscribe((data: unknown) => {
                    resolve(data);
                }, (err: any) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    }
```

i want to post and get methond to backend but i cant fix this code

```
.map
```

this doesnt work,

if i could fix this .map method it will be done

Answer (score 1):

You want to use RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) method.
For that you need to `.pipe` the observable stream like so:

```
  public postForObjecty(endpoint: any, data: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = this.createBasicUrl(endpoint);
      let _data = this.arrangeData(data);
      let headers: any = new Headers()
      let token = `Bearer ${RestProvider.BEARER_TOKEN}`;
      headers.append('Authorization', token);
      this.http.post(url, _data, { headers: headers })
        .pipe(map((res: { json: () => any; }) => res.json()))
        .subscribe((data: unknown) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (err: any) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much, i already tried it but still doesnt work like this
.pipe(map((res: { json: () => any; }) => res.json()))

"""""""""Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<{ json: () => any; }, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Object, any>'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'json' is missing in type 'Object' but required in type '{ json: () => any; }'.  """"""""

Comment: but also my angular version 14 ı forgot to tell that can you help me to fix it as like this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default the Angular `HttpClient` will handle processing the JSON response for you. Assuming you are using this service, this means your `map` here is not necessary and can be removed entirely.

```
public postForObjecty(endpoint: any, data: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = this.createBasicUrl(endpoint);
      let _data = this.arrangeData(data);
      let headers: any = new Headers()
      let token = `Bearer ${RestProvider.BEARER_TOKEN}`;
      headers.append('Authorization', token);
      this.http.post(url, _data, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe((data: unknown) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (err: any) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

If you do need the full response, such as the HTTP status code you can pass `observe: 'response'` into the `options` object the `post` function accepts. The [Angular documentation goes into good detail on this](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response).

As an FYI, in older versions of Angular that had a now deprecated service called `Http` and you would need to call `.json()` all the time.